# Sandbox with CPU and Memory Quote?

Tags: sandbox, quote

Is it possible to run a program inside of sandbox with given CPU, memory and time quote?

Somethign like:

```
$ run-in-sandbox -cpu "15%" -memory "100Mb" \
-forbid-fs-access -forbid-network-access-except-for-port 3000    
-duration "30sec" -run "some-program-name with-some-arguments"
```

If it's not possible to run a general program in such a way, is it possible to run some specific language, like Java, Lua, Ruby, Python, JavaScript (they say there's some safe JS engine in Java)?

Comment: this sounds more like a task for virtualization than sandboxing. just as a clue where you might find a solution. which OS would you prefer?

Comment: Unix-like OS would be the best for my case.